# Retain last context menu item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have added many items to menu. On form right clicking menu popup opens and user can scroll down menu items. When right clicking on form again it should retain from same menu item position where user is scrolled up to.

In VB 6 it will retain last position every time but in C# I'm not able to achieve it.

Comment: So you want to scroll to a certain item? [Hacky way](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/2ff0b52a-8028-413e-bd4c-16fd45391e55/how-to-navigate-to-a-context-menu-strip-item-that-is-not-in-the-visible-range-using-the-keyboard?forum=winforms).

Comment: You can retain the last selection If you save/persist the last (user selected) menu and sub menu index. Before you retain, check for any last indices , if so use  it to position the menu or else it assume to be the first time.

Comment: Actually the instance of `ContextMenuStrip` in C# class should maintain `AutoScrollOffset` property value (which is scroll position). You are probably generating menu dynamically? Can you show how exactly you adding items and displaying menu? Maybe it's also OS/framework version related.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually very easy to achieve, you just have to remember scroll position:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add($"Menu {i:00}"); // add some items;

        // remember the scroll position upon closing and restore it upon opening menu
        var point = Point.Empty;
        ContextMenuStrip.VisibleChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (ContextMenuStrip.Visible)
                ContextMenuStrip.AutoScrollOffset = point;
            else
                point = ContextMenuStrip.AutoScrollOffset;
        };
    }
}
```

In this example I am using same instance of `ContextMenuStrip`, so above code is not doing anything useful. But if you generate context menu dynamically, then you may want to remember `AutoScrollOffset` of old menu and set it for the new one.